# dynamic tables with flask

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2, dynamic-tables

I'm using flask-microframework.
Was trying to add a row to my table

For that DOM manipulation I use jQuery append function like this one.

```js
$("#querytable").find('tbody').append("<tr><td>aaaa</td><td>aaaa</td><td>aaaa</td></tr>");
```

This one is working for like 2 seconds and after that the old state is rolled back as if i never did some change to the table.

Why does it roll back the changement? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. There was a  around that button which triggered the jquery manipulation. Deleted that and everythings works fine.